# Type guard with "is" in return of function doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote type guard function with using "is" in type of return of function, and have type error

> TS2322: Type 'Test1' is not assignable to type 'T extends "NAME" ?
> Test2 : Test1'.

```
interface Test1 {
    id: string;
}

interface Test2 extends Test1 {
    code: number;
}

type typeName = 'NAME' | 'FOO';

const isTest = (obj: Test1 | Test2, name: typeName): obj is Test2 => {
    return name === 'NAME';
};

const foo = <T extends typeName>(name?: T): T extends 'NAME' ? Test2 : Test1 => {
    const test1: Test1 = {id: 'str'};
    const test2: Test2 = {...test1, code: 12};

    const obj = isTest(test1, name) ? test2 : test1;



    return isTest(test1, name) ? test2 : test1; //here I get an error TS2322: Type 'Test1' is not assignable to type 'T extends "NAME" ? Test2 : Test1'.
};
```

If I replace `isTest(test1, name) ? test2 : test1` to `isTest(test1, name) ? test1 : test2` the error will not appear, but logic will be not correct.
Pls help to resolve it

Comment: You'll need to use an assertion or some other hack to get around it as the compiler is not able to reason about conditional types with generic type parameters.

Comment: ① Why is `name` optional? That just causes an error you're not asking about and is therefore distracting; could you make it a required param? ② TS can't follow generic conditional type logic; we'd need something like [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) to be implemented, and it's not part of the language yet.  To resolve it you'll just need to use a type assertion as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wg8x6N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't use typescript but try : return isTest(test1, name) ? test2 : test1 as T extends 'NAME' ? Test2 : Test1;

Comment: @tatactic Yes, I did the same

Comment: So should someone write up an answer here?  Dmitriy could you respond to my previous comment?

Comment: @jcalz I solved my issue in the same way as  tatactic suggested

Comment: You solved your issue in the way both of us suggested; my comment says you need to use a type assertion and my [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wg8x6N) showed the exact same code.  It's fine for you to self-answer, but I'm not sure why you didn't see my suggestion.  Is there something better I can do next time?  Inline code in comments I guess?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I didn't notice that you mention about type assertion. I had read comments after applying the solution that is specified here. You answer is fine, nothing else is needing

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issue, I added type assertion in return type `isTest(test1, name) ? test2 : test1 as T extends 'NAME' ? Test2 : Test1;`